# When using Pycharm git pull/push doesn't work

Tags: python, git, github, version-control, pycharm

I'm trying to push/pull from a github repository through Pycharm but when I do so I get errors.  Below are the errors.

When I try to push I get: `Failed with error: unable to access the url.  The requested url returned error 403.`

When I try to pull I get: `pull appears to be a git command, but we were not... (It doesn't continue on in the notification.)`

The url worked for cloning the code into my directory and the pull request is using the correct url but the end result isn't working.  A note is that when I try to push the requested url ends in a '/' character which is not how I entered it.  Also when I shared a link in Slack to a fellow programmer the link correctly popped up in the preview section despite the '/' added in.  Is this a problem with Pycharm or GitHub and if so what can I do to get it resolved?

Please note, this isn't my first time pushing code to GitHub but it is my first time pulling code and either way when I was pushing code previously I had no errors at all.

Edit: The url I'm trying to use is a public repository at https://github.com/lymanhurd/zertz

Comment: Can you post a modified/anonymized version of what your push URL is?

Comment: Posted the url above as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use URL to clone a github repo by pycharm. You just need to input your **credential** (github token or username and password), then you can clone, pull and push successfully. There are two options to set credential in pycharm. Details as below:

#### Input credential in File -> settings option

In pycharm -> File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Github -> input github token or username and password -> Test -> make sure it’s successful -> OK.
[image]

- **Auto by Token:** Github account -> Settings -> select Personal access tokens -> Generate new token -> copy this token in pycharm.
- **Auto by password:** Input your github’s username and password -> Test -> make sure the connection is successful.

#### Input credential when clone from github

Pycharm -> VCS -> checkout from version control -> Github -> auth by token or passwoed -> Login

Then you can commit you changes, or pull and push from your github repo, it can execute successfully.

Comment: Input credential in file is working, I just checked and it said successful.  And I can clone the directory successfully, I just can't push/pull after I clone it.  I was able to push code previously to my own account but I can't push/pull to the account of a collaborator.

Comment: It's also works for collaborators. And I can pull/push to another github repo as a collaborator. Please try again to clone -> make changes -> commit -> push. And also you can connect with the repo admin to make sure you have permissions and still work as a collaborator.

Comment: I actually got it to work using the GitHub website.  What I had to do was take the repository on the original account and forking it to my account.  Then I did a pull request from the website and it worked even though it still doesn't work in Pycharm.  So problem solved in a way but still unresolved about why it doesn't work in Pycharm.

Comment: You can directly clone/pull/push to the collaborator repo (I tested it successfully). Assume your github account is `https://github.com/user1`, and the repo you works as a collacorator is `https://github.com/user2/repo2`. To clone the `repo2` in pycharm: VCS -> checkout from version control -> github -> change the **Git Repository URL** as `https://github.com/user2/repo2` -> clone -> make changes -> commit -> push.

Comment: Can you push to a collaborator repo successful on github now?